# Creating Hive Tables via Informatica Big Data Edition

Tags: hadoop, hive, informatica, bigdata

I am an old Informatica PowerCenter 8 guy and am heading up a team using Informatica Big Data Edition 9.5.1.  I have a question regarding Hive.  Can Informatica build Hive tables or do they have to be built separately?  If they can be built when 'Not Exists', what are the steps?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: Just as in a typical dw environment, Informatica is used to query and populate the tables and not really create them unless you have special cases (e.g. temp tables). The same goes for Hive and this being a relatively new Informatica connector, most likely the Hive structures need to exist prior to Informatica trying to query and or populate them.  You can always do some special code in the pre-session via shell scripts though I have not tried this with Hive.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the below option in PC, this generate/create the HIVE tables

"Generate And Load Hive Table"
This is available only in PC, with Power Exchange for Hadoop
The way this works is, PC will first load into an HDFS file and then will create an HIVE definition on this and make sure you select "Externally Managed Hive Table", so that PC will create an external table.

Although at the mapping level, you need to define flat file as your target